# О названии города

Tags: семантика

Почему название города Санкт-Петербург РФ так пишется, ведь у города есть русское название Петроград и этот город являлся колыбелем революции?

Comment: Колыбель женского рода, поэтому колыбелью.

Answer (score 3):

В начале 90-х годов ХХ века городу вернули его исконное название "Санкт-Петербург", которое было изменено на "Петроград" в 1914 году, когда началась первая мировая война, в которой Россия воевала против Германии, в связи с чем немецкое слово "Петербург" было заменено на русский аналог

Comment: За всеми этими переименованиями как-то позабыли, что что *исходное* название было Санкт-Питербурх.

Comment: Пётр, наверно, был не очень силён в грамматике, а его окружение не смело его поправлять, если даже видело его царскую ошибку. Другое дело - Н. С. Хрущёв: его "к коммунизьму" и "к социализьму" в газеты попасть никак не могло... Или "Питербурх" - действительно голландское слово?

Comment: Напрасно Вы так о Петре думаете.
Подтверждаю, это название вполне соответствует голландской фонетике, насколько она вообще может быть передана русскими буквами. 
На немецкие лад город переделали позднее, при Екатерине.

Comment: Спасибо за нфрормацию. Поправлю мнение о Петре, но не могу простить ему, что он сажал врагов на кол и смотрел, дожидаясь, когда он дадут дуба (иногда 8 часов). Даже Сталин был благороднее, просто расстреливая (забыл, правда, про его застенки)

Comment: Это История. 
Не в том смысле, что дело давнее, а в том, не имеет отношения к грамматике, фонетике и я зыку вообще. Здесь обсуждать личность Петра в деталях не хотелось бы, я-то говорил исключительно о его грамотности в конкретном случае.

Comment: Петербу́рг

народн. Питенбу́р, Петенбу́р(х), олонецк. (Кулик.), арханг. (Подв.), сиб. (ЖСт. 16, 2, 35). Петр I назвал основанный им город в 1703 г. – Санкт-Питербурх, официально Санкт-Питерсбург. Первое соответствует голл. Pieterburg, а второе – нем. Petersburg; см. Унбегаун, RЕS 9, 272 и сл. Житель П. называется петербу́ржец, народн. питенбу́р, мн. -ы, арханг. (Подв.1). С 1914 г. назывался Петрогра́д (так уже в поэзии Пушкина), совр. Ленингра́д.

••

1 В словаре Подв. сказано: "Так называли крестьян, которые находились на заработках в Петербурге".

Comment: . "С 1914 г. назывался Петрогра́д (так уже в поэзии Пушкина)"  - 1914 год и Пушкин?

Comment: Ларf. При Пушкине это было неофициальным, "народным" названием.

Comment: Я знаю. Просто в комментарии об этом нет. И получается странность.

Comment: To Лapf  Ну, почему же странность?Скопирован сжатый текст из этимолог.словаря.Конечно,составитель мог бы указать примеры("Над омраченным Петроградом...","И всплыл Петрополь как тритон..." Медный всадник),но лаконичность в первую очередь.И так вроде ясно.

Comment: Странность получается из-за недостаточности первой части предложения. С 1914 года назывался Петроград. А пример приводится гораздо более раннего употребления. Ведь Вы не будете утверждать, что Пушкин - это век двадцатый. Во избежании этого следовало бы написать: С 1914 года назывался Петроград(неофициально гораздо ранее, так уже в поэзии Пушкина).

Comment: Пушкин  писал  "град  Петров",  "Петроград",  "Петрополь" - что связывает наименование  города  с  самим  Петром,  а  не  его  небесным  покровителем.  Мне  эти  названия  не  кажутся  неофициальными,  а  именно авторскими,  поэтическими.  Петроград  был  выбран  как  наиболее  русский  вариант  в  высоком  стиле.  А  может  по  другому  и  не  получалось.  Неофициальный вариант -  Петербург,  разговорный - Питер.

Answer (score 0):

Наверно,  тем,  кто  принимал  решение  о  переименовании  Ленинграда,  не  очень  нравилось  напоминание  о  "колыбели"  революции.

Comment: Принимало решение население, так как вынесено оно было по результатам инициированного Ленсоветом городского референдума,формально названного опросом населения.Отсюда и Ленинградская область, в области не было референдума.

Comment: Две  трети  населения  голосовало  за  сохранение  СССР - и  где  он ?

Comment: Разве мы сейчас об аббревиатуре СССР?

Comment: Нет.  Я  говорю  о  значимости   опросов,  референдумов  и  всяких  голосований  для  практических  решений.

Comment: Наше население всегда было таким: в 30-е годы клеймило позором  врагов народа (народа???), а в годы Хрущёва крайне возмущалось культом личности. Поэтому референдумы в нашей стране - кому они нужны и зачем? Ставить власть в неловкое положение? Или показать населению, что оно не народ?

Comment: @Ларf  
>Я знаю. Просто в комментарии об этом нет. И получается странность.    
  
Это очень похоже на цитату из Фасмера или какого-то аналогичного по стилю подачи материала издания. Надо привыкнуть, что все говорится очень конспективно.